# Can there be no morphisms between two objects in a category?

Tags: category-theory

I recently started studying category theory, and all the books give roughly the same definition of a category:

A category $C$ consists of class of objects $Ob_C$. For each two objects $A, B \in Ob_C$ there is a set (class) of morphisms $Hom(A, B)$, ... etc.

However none of these books says that $Hom(A, B)$ **can't** be empty (however, it is not claimed that it **can** be empty).

So, I have a question if $Hom(A, B)$ can be empty (except in those cases when it must be not empty because of the composition rule). I would be very grateful if someone would give a source where this is clearly stated.

Also if $Hom(A, B)$ can be empty, than what is the name for categories in which all the objects are connected (something like fully connected category probably)?

Comment: In the category of sets let $A$ be nonempty and $B$ be empty.

Comment: It can be empty. The empty set is a set.

Comment: In the category of fields, there are no morphisms between fields of different characteristics.

Comment: You can also construct a two object category whose only morphisms are the identities on the objects and show that that forms a category.

Comment: Thank you, I just thought there was a restriction that the hom-set should be non-empty, so now I understand there is no such a restriction

Comment: An ordered set can be seen as a category. The elements are the objects, for two elements = objects $a,b$ there is exactly one morphism iff $a\le b$. Then we have an empty set of homomorphisms in this category (in case of a partial ordering) when $a,b$ are not comparable.

Comment: There's no special name for a category in which $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$ is never empty, as there's nothing particularly interesting about such categories. There is the notion of a *connected* category, but that means a category in which you can always "get from" $A$ to $B$ via morphisms, but possibly zigzagging, as in $A\to C\leftarrow D\to B.$